PyTesseract and 7 segment numbers, how to get confidence of recognition?
I need to recognize digits on 7 seg clocks(see picture below), so I use following python code:
  def detect_date(image: cv2.UMat, bbox:list) -> datetime:
    
   
     gry1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)        
     thr1 = cv2.threshold(gry1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
   
     data = pytesseract.image_to_data(thr1, lang="7seg", config="--psm 6  digits", output_type= Output.DICT)
     return data 

I found 7seg train data here and used code chung
I test with this image -- . The problem is that retunr result of tesseract fn image_to_data is following:

{'level': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'page_num': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'block_num':
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'par_num': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'line_num': [0, 0, 0, 1,
1], 'word_num': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'left': [0, 15, 15, 15, 15], 'top':
[0, 5, 5, 5, 5], 'width': [330, 300, 300, 300, 300], 'height': [70,
63, 63, 63, 63], 'conf': [-1,
-1, -1, -1, 0], 'text': ['', '', '', '', '205215068']}

First of all, I don't understand why I got returned array of 5 items? What does it mean?
Next, I don't understand confidence levels? Mathcing conf array with text it seems
that properly recognized text( digits) have 0 confidence. Why is that? What I'm doing wrong?
If I use  config="--psm 6" (omit digits parameter), then output is following:

{'level': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], 'page_num': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'block_num': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'par_num': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'line_num': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'word_num': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
'left': [0, 15, 15, 15, 15, 179], 'top': [0, 5, 5, 5, 13, 5], 'width':
[330, 300, 300, 300, 142, 136], 'height': [70, 63, 63, 63, 55, 54],
'conf': [-1, -1, -1, -1, 41, 30], 'text': ['', '', '', '', "'Z0S52Z",
'IS068']}

It has wrong recognitions but confidence make more sense now (at least not 0).
Can I got confidence for each digits or for whole string (numbers) only?
I'm quite new to OCR and tesseract so will be thankfull for any help and advices.
Thanks in advance.

Tesseract tracks the confidence for each letter internally, but it only returns an average value for the whole "word".  I don't think it counts numbers as a word.  Numbers are pretty easy, and your image has high contrast, so there should never be an issue.  You have the source, if you want to dig in.

@TimRoberts: Thank you for reply. A little bit clearer now. But why for parameters lang="7seg", config="--psm 6  digits" I got 0 conf and why it returns array of 5 elements where needed text is 5th element?

@TimRoberts: Also, can you recommend mode to recoginze decimal digits? I mean not numbers only but with dots , smth like "20.52.15.068" ?

Have you read the documentation?  It organizes things at 5 levels: page, block, paragraph, line, and word.  Your detections happen at the word level, level 5.  The first 4 levels are blank, and you should ignore them.  You're never going to get the dots.    There are dots all over your image.  If you get 9 digits, you know exactly where the dots go.
